# Inset Box-Shadow for Container DIV to overlay other block elements within

Tags: css

I have a container `<div>` that wraps around 5 other `<div>`s.  I would like to apply a `box-shadow: inset` property to the container div, so it looks like all the elements within that container are beneath it and the shadow is 'on top' of them.

Problem is, it seems that the `<div>` elements within the container appear on top, and hide the shadow.  I have tested the container `<div>` to ensure that the `box-shadow` effect is being applied properly by removing any one of the divs within it.  I have also tried adjusting the `z-index`'s of all of the elements in order to adjust what elements are on top of what.

Am I able to accomplish this effect using the HTML structure I have now?  Would resorting to a `position:absolute` div positioned over the container be able to create this effect?

Please see example - http://jsfiddle.net/mDcKz/

Many thanks SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes try this:

```
.container {
position:absolute; display:block;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
height:100%; width:100%;
box-shadow:inset 0 0 20px #000000;
background:none;
z-index:10 !important;
pointer-events:none;
}
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh, so the `pointer-events` property can determine if that block element is 'accessible' even though it is overlaying.  Awesome stuff.  Any chance you could edit this answer to reflect the whole answer for future visitors?  Thanks again!

Comment: @RCNeil what browser did you get this to work in? I tried using this example and the container's box-shadow was NOT overlaying the child elements.

Comment: I think the newest version of Chrome.  A lot of the browsers I tested with ignored the pointer-events property, so I just ended up scrapping the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
.container {
position:absolute; display:block;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
height:100%; width:100%;
box-shadow:inset 0 0 20px #000000;
background:none;
z-index:10 !important;
} 
.subcontainer {position:absolute; display:block;z-index:5 !important;height:100%;     width:100%;}

<div class="container">

<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="subcontainer">
<div class="divider red"></div>
<div class="divider yellow"></div>
<div class="divider green"></div>
<div class="divider orange"></div>
<div class="divider gray"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works, but since it's z-index is on top of the containing elements, they are inaccessible.  There is no way to accomplish this while keeping them accessible is there?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue applying box-shadow to a container, this is the solution that worked for me:-

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="graph">

    <section>
        <div>
            <span class="danger" style="height: 29.33333333333333%;">Failed</span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <span class="safe" style="height: 70.66666666666667%;">Sent</span>
        </div>
    </section>

</div> <!-- END GRAPH -->
```

**CSS Code**

```
    .graph {
width: 280px;
height: 300px;
position: aboslute;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
z-index: 999;
}

.graph section {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: table;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
z-index: -1;
background: orange;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.graph section div {
display: table-row;
position: relative;
}

.graph section span {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}
```

With this the box-shadow overlays the child elements and the child element is accessible too.